# Is 「してはならないとさしとめる」 a double negative?

Tags: negation

In a Japanese dictionary entry for 禁止, I recently came across:

> してはならないとさしとめること

1. **してはならない:** Literally this means "*as little as* (は) doing (して), doesn't become (ならない)".  More idiomatically: "don't do this".
2. **Xと差し止める**. This means "prohibits X".

So putting these together, don't we get

> It's prohibited that you *don't do* this.

which is the opposite of the intended meaning?

> It's prohibited that you *do* this.

**Question:** Is the phrase "してはならないとさしとめる" a situation where you should interpret a double negative as if it weren't a double negative?

Comment: The short answer: not a double negative

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This `と` is for quoting. So it's equivalent to:

> 「してはならない」と差し止める

Or "*prohibiting from doing, saying 'you can't do that'*".